# NegativeArray exception in android

Tags: android

In my android application,i am parsing a text file of about 1500Kb and saving into database.
But if i am trying to run this in andrioid emulator i am receiving Negative Array exception.The same application runs fine in device.

Could anyone please let me know if i can solve this issue anyhow ?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please post some more info, for exemple the error stacktrace, and the bit of code where it originated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to load the data by activity. Try to use array adapter to load the array or give us more detail regarding this, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the text file is on the device make sure you have permission to read it. 
PS. I don't just mean in the manifest. You need to navigate to the emulated phone settings->permissions and see if you have them for your app.